# Overriding an htaccess file within a sub-folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter, and I've separated out the resources (CSS, JS, Images, etc.) out of the Application folder, into a folder like so: root/resources. CodeIgniter has the typical htaccess file in the root folder, and the contents are:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|docs|js|system)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

If I wanted to allow resource files to live inside a sub-folder, inside the application folder, like so: /application/plugins/some_plugin_name/resources. What contents would I put inside the htaccess file inside the above resources folder that would allow me to access CSS, JS, and other resources files like images, etc.?

This is in regards to future plugins as well, so the "some_plugin_name" folder can be anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jon Lin was close, but there is an additional rule to add onto it. Here's the complete htaccess file that works inside the resources folder. You may want to add it to any folders below the resources folder (but I may be wrong there):

```
RewriteEngine On
allow from all
```

The reason I posted my own answer is because it truthfully took me like 30 minutes to find the answer to it.

Answer (score 1):

You just need this:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

By turning on the rewrite engine inside a subfolder, its rules (which are none) will take precedence over any rules in the parent directory.

Comment: It's still giving me a 403 forbidden error, when I try to access a style.css file directly from the browser. It obviously doesn't work when it's linked to as well.